# Displaying time based logs in in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, logging, highcharts

I need to display time value of some logs which I fetch from a device,on X-axis of a column graph. The column graph has constant values for Y-axis, basically I want the logs to be shown as sticks as the logs are fetched.

The logs have the following date,time format : 2015-05-07T06:08:54.430062Z

I understand this is the ISO format, so I convert "06:08:54.430062" to milliseconds using

```
var myDate = new Date(dt);          
var result = myDate.getTime();
```

The result obtained is like this 1430978934438. It so happens that when I convert I get similar values for other logs as well, even if they have a different time instant.

So suppose I have 10 logs, the graph only shows 4 of them. I use

```
var value=10;// this is a fixed constant value, since I want the log sticks to be of same height.
series.addPoint([result , value], false, false);
```

How can I see all the logs as sticks corresponding to each log entry ?

If you need more information, let me know. I am fairly new to HighCharts and JS, so any help in the right direction would be really helpful.

Thanks

Added code below

```
for (var i = 0; i < nSeries; i++) {         
 dt=jsonData[i].isodate;
 var myDate = new Date(dt);         
 var result = myDate.getTime();         
 var series = mychart.series[0];
 series.addPoint([result, value], false, false);
}

mychart.redraw();


    instance.create = function(Highcharts, container) {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var self = this;
        mychart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: container,
                defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                plotBorderWidth: 1,
                showAxes: true,
                animation: Highcharts.svg 
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Logs'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                events: {
                    setExtremes: function (e) {
                        console.log('e.min: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.min) +
                                ' | e.max: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.max) + ' | e.trigger: ' + e.trigger);
                        if (e.trigger) {
                            self.autoScroll = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S.%L', this.x) + '<br/>'+this.key;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: null
                }
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Logs',
                data: [],
                stack: 'LogStack'
            }]
        });
    };
```

Comment: Could you attach all Highcharts related code? I mean creating chart, and adding points. In short: it should work, unless you have exactly the same timestamps. It's interesting that you get displayed only 4logs instead of all of them.

Comment: I attached the creating chart and plotting points code in my question.  The issue is that  converting timestamps like this "06:08:54.430062" ,"06:08:54.430162" gives similar values like 1430978934438, hence the graph cannot be rendered properly for each value.

Comment: Oh, now I see. So you have tow points in distance of ... 0.1ms ? I'm not sure if `Date()` in is able to handle such dates. I would do something like this: `var myDate = new Date(dt); var result = myDate.getTime() +  parseFloat("0." +  dt.substring(dt.length - 3, dt.length))`. -> as result you will get something like this: `1430978934930.162`.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, now the values do come differently but strangely enough I still see 3 -4 logs only.It's probably got to do with the spacing between the values on the x-axis, how can we control this so that all these values are displayed properly? mychart.xAxis[0].setExtremes() function needs to be set I think, any help on this ?

Comment: I set the min and max values in setExtremes, they are as follows  
MIN:1431012387241.75 MAX:1431012507339.43
e.min: 2015-05-07 20:56:27 | e.max: 2015-05-07 20:58:27 | e.trigger: undefined. These are the first and last values of the times of the logs respectively. The code is as below  if (this.autoScroll) {
   console.log('setExtremes');
   console.log("MIN:"+minval+"MAX:"+result);
   mychart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minval, result, false, false);
  } 
  else {   
   mychart.xAxis[0].update({ min: minval, max: result }, false);
  }

Comment: Highcharts will automatically calculate extremes, so I don't think there is any issue. Could you provide full dataset to see what is wrong?

Comment: The time logs are as below                                        Time:1431323442039.14 
Time:1431323442041.18
Time:1431323522114.97 
Time:1431323562128.05 
Time:1431323562131.42 
Time:1431323562131.56 
Time:1431323562132.36 
Time:1431323562132.26 
Time:1431323562132.05 
Time:1431323562132.43. The graph appears for only 1431323442041.18,1431323522114.97 and then the scrollbar ends

Comment: What is `nSeries` in your case? Shouldn't be there `jsonData.length` ? Also, I guess, you can see these points, because those are really close. Then you have huge gap and another three very close points. Try to zoom-in into the first one visible point: http://jsfiddle.net/14jL9no0/15/ (drag&drop). You can use categories instead, to make equal space between points, but I'm not sure if this is the best idea: http://jsfiddle.net/14jL9no0/17/

Comment: Thanks Pawel. So probably its a limitation to show such sequence of values using HighCharts, unless we change those value types to 'category' rather than 'datetime'? Another way to make equal space between points is to set 'ordinal: true' in xAxis retaining the same 'datetime' type. But what I'm looking for is to show some time interval which depicts the occurence of logs with respect to time.

Comment: If you have Highstock, then indeed `ordinal` works similar to the categories. You can also consider [`breaks`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.breaks) in the axis. Of course, you need to calculate breaks. Another solution I can suggest is to manipulate your data. In short, round your values to 1second (or at least 1ms), then using for example flags, you can highlight more points in the same point (but timestamp must be the same, difference for example 2ms won't work, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/14jL9no0/18/ ).